# Why does the data change when the state is updated?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vuex

I'm using vue with [vuex](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuex), and I just spent hours tracing the problem. Maybe you could help.

My question is why does after I create a new team using `newTeam` method from **CreateTeam.vue**, the `listOfTeams` from my **Team.vue** was also updated?

- I never made a subscribe or watch or any watcher in my **Team.vue**. Why does the `listOfTeams` get updated when I add a new team?
- Is this exact behavior of vuex? Please enlighten me.

---

Here is my **Team.vue**

```
data() {
    return { listOfTeams: [] }
},

methods: {
    loadRecord: async function() {
        const response = await this.$store.dispatch("teams/load");
        this.$store.commit("teams/intitialize", response.data);
        this.listOfTeams = response.data;
    }
},
```

**CreateTeam.vue**

```
methods: {
    newTeam: async function() {
        const response = await this.$store.dispatch("team/store", formData);
        this.$store.commit("teams/add", response.data);
    }
}
```

And here **teams.js (module)** that I'm using

```
const state = { record: {}, };
const actions = {
    store({commit,state}, payload) { return httpFile().post('/teams', payload); },
    
    load({ commit, state }, payload = "") { return http().get("teams" + payload); }
};

const mutations = {
    intitialize(state, payload) { state.record = payload.data.data; },
    
    add(state, payload) { state.record.unshift(payload.data); },
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript is a reference-based language (the simplest way to think to it is that all variables and members are pointers).

This means for example

```
let x = [];
let a = {y: x}; // Doesn't make a copy of x
console.log(a.y.length); // output is 0
x.push(10);
console.log(a.y.length); // output is 1
```

`a.y` was empty just after creation, but the member is still pointing to the same array as `x`, so adding elements to `x` also adds elements to `a.y` because they're both pointers to the same object.

In your code

```
this.listOfTeams = response.data;
```

is not making a copy of `response.data` thus if that object is modified (e.g. it is emptied and new values are added to it instead of creating a new fresh array) then your member will be changed too.

To solve you can write:

```
this.listOfTeams = response.data.slice();
```

This way your member class will have its own array and won't be dependent on some other code messing with `response.data` after you assigned it.

Comment: thanks so much Sir! The tutorial video does not use `slice()`, now I learned more.

Answer (score 1):

This is a JavaScript object reference issue.

1. You get a response from some async HTTP call, stored in the `response` variable (an object)
2. You commit that object (well, its `data` property) to your store in your `intitialize` mutation

   ```js
   state.record = payload.data.data
   ```

   Here, `payload.data` and `response.data` are the same object
3. You then set your list of teams `data` property to that same object

   ```js
   this.listOfTeams = response.data
   ```

At no point in this do you ever break the object reference so when you next add a new team with your `add` mutation, it directly manipulates the store data using `Array.prototype.unshift()`...

```js
state.record.unshift(payload.data)
```

You are altering all three of `response.data.data`, `this.listOfTeams` and `state.record` because they are all the same object reference.

This is why it's a good idea to treat your store state as immutable as well as break object references when making direct assignments

```js
const mutations = {
  intitialize (state, { data }) {
    state.record = {...data.data} // break reference via spread
  },
  add(state, { data }) {
    state.record = [data, ...state.record] // immutable
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're or will use [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/), you can try using [_.cloneDeep](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#cloneDeep) to break the reference and create a new value based on the previous one